# Laravel app downloading all assets again on every route request

Tags: php, laravel

I have a strange error in my Laravel(5.6)/app. Whenever there is any route request in the app, all css, js, bootstrap and icons files reload all over again in the browser. I'm debugging this app from last 2 days. And I have no clue what's going on.

I worked on this project a few days ago and it was working fine then I started working on some other project and after a couple of days when I worked again on this project to add some new features, it is behaving like this. Whenever I request any route in the app, all the assets download and load again in the browser. I didn't provide any code sample here because I don't know where the error might be.

If there have been an error in some particular file then that particular route would have behave that way. But all routes reload all the assets all over again. So I just want your opinion is this ever happens to you and how should I tackle it?

If you wanna recreate this project then here is the GitHub link. [Git Repo](https://github.com/OmEr1112/Laravel-Shopping-Cart) . Recreating this project is very easy. Just create a database. run migrations and then seed the database. For sass and js ,run 'npm run dev' if needed.

Update: Solution to this problem is, don't use buit-in server of laravel, it sucks. Use any php development stack like xampp, wamp etc. and it will work fine.

Comment: Github url returns 404

Comment: Just a guess maybe you have to add them in your htaccess (mime types not the pathes) with a cache rule? Google for apache cache control or http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_expires.html as an example

Comment: just remove the last bracket from the url. and it will work. and Im looking into this htaccess thing. thanks for your time